# Show that there are less injective than surjective functions from A to B

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Title says it all. I need to show that there are less injective than surjective functions from A to B, A and B finite. Now, I know there are $\textrm{A}_{n}^{m}=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$ where |A|= m and |B|= n  injective functions but I do not have any idea how to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure the title does say it all. These are finite sets, right? What are $m$ and $n$, and what does $A_n^m$ mean? What if $|A| < |B|$, in which case there are $0$ surjective functions, but plentiful injective functions?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I edited it.

Comment: That's better, but I'm still not sure what you mean by $A^m_n$, and I still think the result is not true. Are you sure there are no other conditions on $A$ and $B$?

Comment: The problem does not say any other conditions.

Comment: I can't really help much then. I will repeat that, if $|A| < |B|$, then there are no surjective functions. If $|A| > |B|$, then there are no injective functions. If $|A| = |B|$, then every injective function is surjective, and vice-versa; there are the same number of injections and surjections.

Comment: I get what you are saying and it makes sense indeed. Maybe the problem is wrong.

Comment: It's interesting to compare the number of injections from $A$ to $B$ with the number of surjections from $B$ to $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are supposed to prove that there are fewer injective functions from $A$ to $B$ than there are surjective functions from $B$ to $A$...

Let $\mathcal I$ be the set of injections $A\to B$ and let $\mathcal S$ be the set of surjections $B\to A$. Then you can give an injection $\phi:\mathcal I\to \mathcal S$ as follows. Arrange the elements of $B$ in a circle. Given an injection $f:A\to B$, divide the circle of elements of $B$ into $|A|$ arcs, where the clockwise-most element of each arc is in the image of $f$. Then $\phi(f):B\to A$ is the map which sends each element of $b$ to the $a\in A$ for which $f(a)$ is the clockwise endpoint of the arc containing $b$.

To see that $\phi$ is injective, note that $f$ can be recovered from $g=\phi(f)$ as follows: for any $a\in A$, $g^{-1}(\{a
\})$ will be a contiguous arc whose clockwise-most element is $f(a)$.